# Annotate timeseries plot by merging two timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

Given I have two time series (or two columns in a data frame) like this:

```
rng1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=3, freq='H')
ts1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts2 = pd.Series(['HE','NOT','SHE'], index=rng)
```

I want to do a plot of `ts1.plot()` where `ts2` is used to annotate ts1 time series, HOWEVER I only want to annotate the timestamps that are `<> NOT`.

What I have found so far is using markers would be what Im looking for. For example having one marker for 'HE' and another for 'SHE' and No marker for 'NOT'. However I cant figure out how to use another time series as input and only to annotate the timestamps <> some value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas dataframe `groupby` method to split the dataset by the labels you're using and just ignore the values you don't want to plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=3, freq='H')
ts1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts2 = pd.Series(['HE','NOT','SHE'], index=rng)
df = pd.concat([ts1, ts2], keys=['foo', 'bar'], axis=1)

ax = None # trick to keep everything plotted on a single axis
labels = [] # keep track of the labels you actually use
for key, dat in df.groupby('bar'):
    if key == 'NOT':
        continue
    labels.append(key)
    ax = dat.plot(ax=ax, marker='s', ls='none', legend=False)
# handle the legend through matplotlib directly, rather than pandas' interface
ax.legend(ax.get_lines(), labels)
plt.show()
```